# Can RabbitMQ 2.1.0 allow guest user remotely?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm running an old version of RabbitMQ (2.1.0) and trying to connected from a remote server with the default username and password of `guest`.  It looks like access is not being allowed. I have tried the suggestion on [RabbitMQ's page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) to set `rabbitmq.conf` to `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].` but this is not working on my version.

I need to be able to allow `guest` access remotely (on internal network).  Before you respond, 'Don't do this its not secure' or 'Upgrade', those are not really options as this is in production and there are other dependencies at this time.

Below is the error message I'm receiving from Bunny/Rails/Ruby

```
   ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:11821160     guest@X.X.X.X:5672, vhost=/, hosts=[###]>: Got an exception when receiving data: IO timeout when reading 7 bytes (Timeout::Error)
   WARN -- #<Bunny::Session:11821160 guest@X.X.X.X:5672, vhost=/, hosts=[####]>: Recovering from a network failure...
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you run RabbitMQ 2.1.0? We are already on version 3.4.3, with several improvements, bug fixes, security fixes, and so on. If you can upgrade, do it ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was not a RabbitMQ issue, but rather the Bunny Gem version.  Downgrading from 1.6 to 1.4 fixed the issue.

https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny#supported-rabbitmq-versions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a password for the guest user

```
rabbitmqctl change_password guest NEW_PASSWORD
```

Than set the permissions for the vhost you need (looks like / in your case)

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / ".*" ".*" ".*"    # this is full access
```

Connect from remote with the user: guest password: NEW_PASSWORD